# UIBarButtonItem nextResponder call

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

Looking on the web (https://github.com/Musixmatchdev/ObjectiveHeaders/blob/master/Headers/iPhoneOS6.0.sdk/UIKit/UIBarButtonItem.h) I found that UIBarButtonItem is implemented **nextResponder** selector.

However that's not part of the public API of UIBarButtonItem but it is in UIResponder class (which sadly UIBarButtonItem does not inherit from).

Am I authorized to use it or could it be refused by Apple ? (I would have asked on Apple Forums but it's gonna be down for a while I believe :)

Thanks a lot,

Jack Pardshe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a solution for my specific issue:

I forward calls to [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]] selector which in turn (with the from parameter) uses UIBarButtonItem nextResponder. So this is an indirect reference to it using public API.

However I think that Apple is just using a respondsToSelector:@selector(nextResponder) on an id parameter in this method. So doing the same thing inside a custom code (write a method which take an id parameter and then call nextResponder on it) might also be a solution to use nextResponder selector whithout being seen as using the private API but this is just an hypothesis.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, UIBarButtonItem is based on crippled UIBarItem, and neither of them implements nextResponder method. So, it's considered a private (non-public) API, and according to [Apple App Store review guideline](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) pt.2.5, "Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected".

*Note: Apple Developer portal is down now, but one can easily find the guide on the net*

P.S. Please describe the reason of using nextResponder of UIBarButtonItem - I'm sure there are more than one way to achieve it.

Comment: I wanted to proxy action/target on UIBarButtonItem to do some check conditions on them before triggering (or not) the real action/target setted by the user. But a nil target won't be handled by the responder chain in this case

Comment: Private nextResponder of UIBarButtonItem points to UINavigationBar. Since UINavigationBar is based on UIResponder, it's nextResponder is public, and you could absolutely legally handle your checks there.

Comment: Note: no one can give you a 100% guarantee that nextResponder of every UIBarButtonItem you create will always point to it's UINavigationBar. However since that fact perfectly fits in Apple's responder chain design pattern I think it's safe to use in production.